# How can I attack move click to kite while only targeting champs?

Tags: league-of-legends

So the attack move click is by default "a" then click. (I use shift click when kiting)

There is also the default key "tilde (~)" that will allow to target only champions.

The main problem is that when kiting an enemy champions and if there is an enemy minions closer to me than the enemy champions, I would start attacking the minion rather than the champions (when using "attack move click")

So is there any key binding to allow for attacking move click to kite while only targeting champs? If not, is there any "trick" that would allow for such move?

NB: I found some kind of answer [on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/summonerschool/comments/2cij3s/how_can_i_attack_move_click_to_kite_while_only/) but I don't understand it, and I'm not sure it is actually a correct answer.

Comment: don't attack-move. Move and then attack the champ then move away again. Repeat...

Comment: @bolov At high attack speeds that's basically impossible to do without dropping most of your damage output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is no way to change A's attack move command to only target champions. The default key "tilde" does not target the same way the "a" key does.

The A key, as you might know, targets the closest enemy minion, monster or champion for an auto attack. The Tilde key, *when held down*, allows you to only target champions with an auto attack,and works  with any targeted spells as well. Useful for tower dives or champions standing in a group of minions or jungle camps.

However, there is an [experimental change](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/gameplay-balance/E49lA2pw-experimental-attack-move-change-going-to-pbe) on the PBE, that changes the functionality of attack moving. Note that this **may or may not** make it to live and is currently only being tested. The above link has more information about this change and some pictures showing functionality, but below are the basics of what is being tested, taken from that post.

> With this change, you will instead attack the unit closest to your
>   cursor when clicking attack move, within specific constraints:
>   1. The enemy must be within 250 units of your cursor click
>   2. The enemy must be at least within 50 units of your max attack range (If the enemy is between your attack range and 50 units past your
>   attack range, you will only "run backwards" to hit them if your cursor
>   was within 50 units of the enemy out of the maximum 250 scan)